# Using null value from SQL Server in iOS, PHP and JSON

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, json, sql-server-2008

The application I am designing consumes JSON objects returned by PHP scripts that select from a SQL Server 2008 database. The problem I am encountering is that when the database is missing a value for a certain field, it returns as a null in JSON. Then when the app parses the JSON (I am using NSJSONSerialization), the dictionary contains a  value. When using this dictionary to populate my view, the application crashes when encountering the null value.

What would be the easiest way to bypass this problem? I am thinking I could just replace all nulls with empty string before the PHP returns the data as JSON; however, that might not be the best solution. Is there a simple way to check in iOS?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for null values you need to see if the object is [`[NSNull null]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
id object = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
if(object == [NSNull null])
{
    //Handle null value
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to check an entire dictionary? Or do I have to pull an object out using key and then check?

Comment: You have to check each object, you can either check each object right after parsing the json and remove/replace with defaults or add `NSNull` handling to whichever classes use and display the values.

Comment: This is very bad! I know there's is no other way but think you have to check for null values explicitly. Just wondering why iOS doesn't consider null as a nil like Android does! The thing is if we execute NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"key"]; and the value is null, it assigns NSNull object to array and we cannot use condition if(array && [array count] > 0) as App will crash because NSNull is not nil, and NSNull doesn't respond to count!!! I have ended up writing macro for each of these throughout my code.